# Searching for the 'p' value in a coin toss simulation

Tags: python, numpy, random

Newbie to coding, attempting to find the 'p' value in a coin toss simulation.
Currently getting the attribute error:

'int' object has no attribute 'sum'.

How could it be? please Help.'''

```
import numpy as np
import random
attempts = 0
t = 0

for I in range (10000):
      attempts = random.randint(2, 30)
      if (attempts.sum >= 22 ):
      t += 1

p = t / 10000 
print(p)
```

Comment: `attempts` is a single integer value between 2 and 29.

Comment: Common statistical usage would define `p` as the chance of a coin showing the target value (usually "heads").  It's not clear what you're doing, as your "coin" can return a rather large range of results, 2-30.  Please describe how your attempted `sum` usage is solving a problem, and what that problem might be.

Comment: "How could it be?" What part do you not understand, exactly? Do you know what an `'int' object` is? Do you know what an `attribute` is? Do you know specifically which `'int' object` is being complained about? Do you *expect* it to have that attribute? If so, why?

Comment: Most of the time tossing a coin will eventually give one an even amount of tosses, and in this case the number of tosses would be  30, but what would the 'p' value be at 22 tosses?

Comment: Did you maybe want `numpy.random.randint(2, size=30)` instead of `random.randint(2, 30)`? (That is, on each loop, you toss 30 coins, and record how often at least 22 of them turn up 'heads'.)

Answer (score 0):

`attempts` is the most recent random integer you generated.  An `int` has no attribute (data field) `sum`.  Since you haven't adequately described what you think your code does, we can't fix the problem.

Python's `sum` *function* adds up a sequence of items; see the documentation for examples.

---

You try to count something with variable `m`, but you give it no initial value.

You set `t` to 0, and later divide it by your loop limit, but you've never changed the value; this will be 0.0.

---

**Update after OP comments**

I think I understand now: you want to estimate the probability of getting at least 22 heads (or whatever side you choose) in a set of 30 tosses of a fair coin.  I'll do my best to utilize your original code.

First of all, you have to toss a fair coin; the function call you made generates a random integer in the range [2, 30].  Instead, you need to do a call such as the below in groups of 30:

```
flip = random.randint(0,1)
```

This gives you a 0 or 1.  Let's assume that we want to count `1` results: this allows us to simply add the series:

```
count = sum(random.randint(0,1) for _ in range(30))
```

This will loop 30 times, put the results in a list, and add them up; there's your count of desired flips.  Now, do 10,000 of those 30-flip groups, checking each for 22 results:

```
import random
t = 0

for i in range (10000):
    count = sum(random.randint(0,1) for _ in range(30))
    if (count >= 22):
        t += 1

p = t / 10000 
print(p)
```

Now, if you want to tighten this even more, use the fact that a successful comparison (i.e. `True`) will evaluate to `1`; `False` will be `0`: make all 10,000 trials in an outer comprehension (in-line `for`):

```
t = sum( 
         sum(random.randint(0,1) for flip in range(30)) > 22
     for trial in range(10000) )
print(t / 10000)
```

`flip` and `trial` are dummy loop variables; you can use whatever two you like.

Finally, it's usually better style to make named variables for your algorithms parameters, such as

```
threshhold  = 22
trial_limit = 10000
flip_limit  = 30
```

and use those names in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to toss a coin 10,000 times and see how many turn up heads (or tails, if you prefer) then this is a simple way to do it. The random.random function returns a number such that 0 <= x < 1, so 50% of the time it should be less than .5.

```
import random

tosses = 100000

t = 0
for i in range(tosses):
    if random.random() < .5:
        t += 1

p = t / tosses
print(p)
```

Comment: You could also do print(f'heads {t}, tails {tosses - t}") to get the number of heads and tails (python 3.6 or later)

Comment: I agree with your code, although, one would say  the p value would be much smaller than 50% with the random.randint(2, 30).

Comment: True, but most coins are 50%. If you want a different probability you can just change .5 to something else.